# Hash Function for 3 Integers

Tags: hash, hashcode

I have 3 non-negative integers and a number n such that

```
0 <= a <= n, 0 <= b <= n, and 0 <= c <= n.
```

I need a one-way hash function that maps these 3 integers to one integer (could be any integer, positive or negative). Is there a way to do this, and if so, how? Is there a way so that this this function can be expressed as a simple mathematical expression where the only parameters are a, b, c, and n?

***Note***: I need this function because I was using tuples of 3 integers as keys in a dictionary on python, and with upwards of `10^10` keys, space is a real issue.

Comment: You've determined that existing hashing algorithms don't work already? Or that using nested dictionaries isn't a workable solution?

Comment: I tried using nested dictionaries, but they don't seem to improve the memory usage much. The existing hashing algorithms do work, but speed is a concern and since this was a one-way hash and with very specific constraints, I thought there might be a faster and simpler way.

Comment: Hashing or not you'll still have the same number of entries-are you sure it's the key "depth" that's causing the issue?

Comment: No, I think it's just that Python allocates much more memory for tuples:
sys.getsizeof((1, 2, 3)) is 72, while sys.getsizeof(100000000) is just 28.

Comment: The first thing which comes to mind is `a * (n + 1)^2 + b * (n + 1) + c`. It won't collide :) Of course, it depends on maximum `n`, so that it can fit into an integer \ 64-bit integer.

Comment: It worked perfectly! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 4):

How about the Cantor pairing function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function)?

Let 
H(a,b) := .5*(a + b)*(a + b + 1) + b

then

H(a,b,c) := .5*(H(a,b) + c)*(H(a,b) + c + 1) + c

You mentioned that you need a one-way hash, but based on your detailed description about memory constraints it seems that an invertible hash would also suffice.

This doesn't use the assumption that a, b, and c are bounded above and below.

Comment: I used an integer version of this and you quickly get overflow when the integers get too large. I note that you use the floating point literal 0.5 -- is this done using floating point to avoid overflow?

Comment: @wcochran Good point, honestly I used this as a way to generate keys for floating point numbers read in from stl files (e.g., 3D printing).  Even for unsigned integers experiencing overflow, I imagine this wouldn't be an issue since you only care about generating mostly unique keys.  (But overflow indeed means that this hash is no longer invertible.)

Comment: @wcochran As for the comment about 0.5, I actually coded this as a divide by 2 (via a reinterpret_cast<size_t> on the arguments) and just let overflow happen.

Answer (score 2):

Augmenting the answer above for a more concise implementation:

```js
int cantor(int a, int b) {
   return (a + b + 1) * (a + b) / 2 + b;
}

int hash(int a, int b, int c) {
   return cantor(a, cantor(b, c));
}
```

The easiest way to understand this is that Cantor algorithm assigns a natural number to every integer pair of numbers.

Once we've assigned a natural number `N = cantor(b, c)`, then we can assign a new unique natural number `M = cantor(a, N)`, which we can use as a hash code and is a unique natural number for every triple a, b, c.

As a more general case, you could hash more integers by just another cantor with the next integer (e.g. `cantor(a, cantor(b, cantor(c, d)))`).

Comment: No hash is collision free where can I found the collision of cantor for 3 integers?